# Excel: How to make a cell look at a column for matches and then input the value of the cell next to the match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a spreadsheet and would like to be able to put in an equation that looks at the specified line in L and then searches J for a match, upon finding a match it will display the cell next to it (the I column).
Such as in "M2" I would put the equation and since it matches "J3" it would show the number 2.

[image: Example]

I have tried using `=IF(...)` but I am unable to figure out how to reference the criteria as a base for the shown term.

Please let me know if you have any ideas, thanks!

Comment: With Office 365, in M2, you can use`= XLOOKUP( L2:L6, J2:J6, I2:I6, 0 )`.

Comment: VLOOKUP() or INDEX() with MATCH(). Many examples on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "INDEX/MATCH" solution for this:

```
=INDEX(I$5:J$9,MATCH(L5,J$5:J$9,0),1)
```

This is based on the following screenshot (with row and column headings):

[image: screenshot]